# Add a download Hyperlink in gridview in visual studios 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, gridview, hyperlink

My problem is simple, I would like to make the last column of my gridview to be a download link to a file in local on my computer.

I have my datatable with 3 columns :

```
User_id, request_id, FilePath
```

FilePath is the path (string) to the file on my computer, what I've been trying is :
In my gridview on the webpage display the 2 first columns (User_id and request_id).
On the 3rd column I added a hyperlink field and tried to link it (with the property DataNavigateUrlField) to the content of the column FilePath.

I've ended up with dead links on which i can't even click, they just change color on mouseover.

Any one have a clue about that ? Thanks a lot

Comment: What code do you use to generate the grid, what HTML gets generated, have you looked at an [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlinkcolumn.datanavigateurlfield.aspx)?

Comment: Actually all the code concerning the gridview (html and c#) is generated by visual studios, that's what i was hoping someone who knows about visual studios behaviour would help me, i've been on asp.net forums and msdn tutorial about datanavigateurl but nothing made the trick. So here i am on stackoverflow

Comment: Please click "View Source" in your browser and look at the [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlinkcolumn.datanavigateurlfield.aspx). Also the C# code is accessible from Visual Studio.

Comment: What do your actual `FilePath` values look like?

Comment: @Filburt c:/directory/file.xxx

Comment: @CodeCaster i looked at the HMTL and nothing look relevant for this issue, as i said this is in my opinion a simple databinding issue with the tool provided by visual studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution could be to use a `TemplateField` for your Hyperlink column:

```
<asp:GridView AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <a href='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FilePath") %>'>
                    <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FilePath")%>
                </a>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

will create the desired output:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <a href='c:/directory/file.xxx'>c:/directory/file.xxx</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

It seems that a `HyperLinkField` does not accept a file path for its `DataNavigateUrlFields`property.

---

I tried to outsmart it by setting the `DataNavigateUrlFormatString` property:

```
<asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFormatString="file:///{0}" DataNavigateUrlFields="FilePath" DataTextField="FilePath" />
```

but the issue remains and will only produce

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <a>c:/directory/file.xxx</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I've come to the same conclusion, HyperLinkField doest not accept FilePath, so i stored them on my server and problem solved, thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

try to use this

```
WebClient.DownloadFile(Uri,String)
```

And read this how to get needed event [hyperlink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlink.aspx)