# Using hyperlink in gridview control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using `gridview` in my ASP.NET web application and using `templatefield` to show a column with hyper link. The hyper link is actually a network path (like `\\X.X.X.X\SampleFolder`).

I want to open the folder when user clicks on the column. Now, the grid shows the expected column with the hyper link applied. But when I click on the column, the path it takes is like `file://X.X.X.X/SampleFolder` and that's the reason, the shared folder path is not getting opened up. It should be the same as - `\\X.X.X.X\SampleFolder`.

Any thoughts?

Comment: tried something like this <a href="file://///servername/foldername/filename.txt">filename.txt</a>

Comment: See my answer on [Add a download Hyperlink in gridview in visual studios 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10435786/205233)

Comment: Didn't try it. Well, the requirement is like - I am querying DB and the result obtained is in the form - \\X.X.X.X\SampleFolder\LastName First Name. Now I am just displaying 'LastName FirstName' to the user and when user clicks on it, it should open - '\\X.X.X.X\SampleFolder\LastName First Name'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `TemplateField` should look something like this:

```
<asp:GridView AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <a href='file:///\\X.X.X.X\SampleFolder\<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "LastName") %> <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FirstName") %>'>
                    <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "LastName") %> <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FirstName") %>'>
                </a>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```